# Laravel authentication with multiple roles

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-7

Hi I'm a beginner at laravel, I have to develop a project for human resources management and I have two roles admin and employee. I followed a tutorial at laracast to build roles and abilities table and everything seems to be working. Now I just installed laravel/ui package and I can see login and register which are working fine with the users I registered in the database. My problem now is that I don't know how to connect things together. How can I check if the logged in user is admin so the admin panel opens. Waiting for your replies. Here is the code;
Error I'm receiving: 419 page expired

This is what I tried but doesn't work

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        // to admin dashboard
        if(auth()->user()->roles()->name === 'admin') {
            return redirect(route('admin'));
        }

        // to user dashboard
        else if(auth()->user()-roles()->name === 'user') {
            return redirect(route('home'));
        }

        abort(404);
    }
```

Routes

```
   Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
    
    Auth::routes();
    
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/admin', 'LoginController@authenticated')->name('admin');
```

users table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

create roles table

```
class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('label')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

        });

        Schema::create('abilities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('label')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

        });

        Schema::create('ability_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->primary(['role_id','ability_id']);

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('ability_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('role_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('roles')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('ability_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('roles')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });

        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->primary(['user_id','role_id']);

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('role_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('roles')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

        });
    }
```

User.php

```
public function roles()
    {
        if(is_string($role))
        {
            $role = Role::whereName($role)->firstOrFail();
        }
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function assignRole($role)
    {
        $this->roles()->sync($role, false);
    }

    public function abilities($role)
    {
       return $this->roles->map->abilities->flatten()->pluck('name')->unique();
    }
```

Role.php

```
class Role extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    
    public function abilities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Ability::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function allowTo($ability)
    {
        $this->abilities()->sync($ability,false);
    }
}
```

Ability.php

```
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    
    public function roles()
    {
        if(is_string($ability))
        {
            $ability = Ability::whereName($ability)->firstOrFail();
        }
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... I don't understand what the particular problem is ... you seem to be checking the role in the `authenticated` method that runs after login .... also everything besides the `return` statement should be removed from your `roles` methods on your models

Comment: I dont know but I get an error 419 I cant seem to access admin view when I log in as an admin user

Comment: 419 is a CSRF token issue ... can you provide your routes?  you are not even getting to the `authenticated` method because of the exception being thrown ... if you did get to that method you would have errors about the `role` method not existing

Comment: No im using the login from the package

Comment: yes ill be posting now the routes

Comment: hoefully those routes are in `web.php` ...  you may have a session issue/cookie issue

Comment: Yes in add.php, I added this route : Route::get('/admin', 'LoginController@authenticated')->name('admin');

And I got this error now;Call to undefined method App\User::role()

Comment: `add.php`? ... you mean `web.php`?

Comment: yes in web.php sorry

Comment: you are apparently authenticated at the moment so it isn't a session/cookie issue ... what are you doing when you get the 419 error?

Comment: Im trying to login, anyway now its giving another error: Undefined variable: role
at this line:     if(is_string($role))

Comment: like I said you should remove everyting besides the `return` statement from the `roles` methods on your model, all those other lines are doing nothing ... and you can't "login" again since you are already logged in

Comment: that does not seem to fix my problem

Comment: okay, good luck

Answer (score 0):

To management roles and permissions I'm using:

```
"santigarcor/laratrust"
```

You can learn more here: https://github.com/santigarcor/laratrust
You can use it like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

if (Auth::user()->isAbleTo('edit-user')) {}
if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) {}
if (Auth::user()->isA('guide')) {}
if (Auth::user()->isAn('admin')) {}
```

This package provides a user interface for the santigarcor/laratrust package

```
"icweb/trusty"
```

You can learn more here: https://github.com/icweb/laratrust-ui

All tables and data will be auto created.

Comment: Hey this should be done by using code, but anyway thank you :)

Comment: I have try a lot of way to find the best solution, just try it. You will find it is the easiest way. Goodluck!